Exercise 2.2.J in Vakil's The Rising Sea (version 2022)
The question is stated below:
If $(X,\mathscr{O}_{X})$ is a ringed space, and $\mathscr{F}$ is an $\mathscr{O}_X$-module, describe how for each $p\in X$, $\mathscr{F}_p$ is an $\mathscr{O}_{X,p}$-module.


I had a unfinished approach, with a problem.
Approach:
Since (in Page 76 of The Rising Sea) the diagram

commutes, we can get

commutes in category of abelian group.
So (horizontal arrows in) the second diagram would induce a map:
$$\text{colim}_{U\in p}\mathscr{O}_X(U)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathscr{F}(U)\to \mathscr{F}_p$$
The problem:
Is tensor product commute with this colimit (in category of abelian group)?
i.e. the following formula holds:
$$\text{colim}_{U\in p}\mathscr{O}_X(U)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathscr{F}(U) \cong \mathscr{O}_{X,p}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathscr{F}_p$$
And $\mathscr{O}_{X,p}$ is a colimit in the category of rings, is it also a colimit in the category of abelian groups?
(Is my approach on the right track?  And hint to the original Exercise 2.2.J, or other references are also welcome)

@arkeet But in your $-\otimes M$, $M$ is a fixed one, which is not my case.
And $\mathscr{O}_{X,p}$ is a colimit in the category of rings, not abelian groups.

I think this answer should basically handle your question - what do you think?
